# Why is this JAGS error appearing in my R output?

Tags: r, bayesian, rjags

So I'm trying to do this bayesian data modeling project and I went back to my notes from my bayesian stats class on rjags where my professor went over a really similar model. I was able to run that one without any issues, but when I adapt it to my model I'm getting an error as my output.

Here is my code:

```
library(rjags)
set.seed(12196)

# Number of bear reports
Y <- black_bears$Y # Number of surveys saying there was a reported bear sighting
N <- black_bears$N # Number of surveys submitted on whether a bear was seen or not
q <- Y/N # proportion of the non-bear sightings submitted

n <- length(Y)
X <- log(q)-log(1-q) # X = logit(q)

data   <- list(Y=Y,N=N,X=X)
params <- c("beta")

model_string <- textConnection("model{
                           # Likelihood
                           
                           for (i in 1:n){
                           Y[i] ~ dbinom(p[i], N[i])
                           logit(p[i] <- beta[1] + beta[2]*X[i])
                           }
                           
                           # Priors
                           beta[1] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
                           beta[2] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
                           }")

model <- jags.model(model_string,data = data, n.chains=2,quiet=TRUE)
update(model, 10000, progress.bar="none")
samples1 <- coda.samples(model, variable.names=params, thin=5, n.iter=20000, progress.bar="none")

plot(samples1)
```

I'm getting presented with this error:
[image: rjags error]

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try logit(p[i]) <- beta[1] + beta[2]*X[i]. I think you have a misplaced bracket.

Comment: @Limey, God I feel dumb. That did it. That, and I had to add n=n to my data = list() line, so it now reads data = list(Y=Y, N=N, X=X, n=n) but now it's running smoothly. Thanks!